# How to find the log line with the most recent time stamp?

Tags: regex, python-3.x, comparison

Currently I am looping through a directory to find/store/display the latest log line containing the version number information. I am finding the log lines with version numbers by using Regex, and I am trying to find the log line with the latest time stamp by comparing them with parse_version.

For example the log lines in the files of my folder looks like this:

```
2018-05-08T15:47:27.752Z 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 > LVL:2 RC: version: 2.12.1.10452

2018-05-08T21:27:14.2049217Z> <INFO >: Version: 2.10.0.23960

2018-05-08T21:18:53.0428568Z> <INFO >: Version: 2.12.1.26051
```

These are just a few examples of the thousands of log lines in the files of my folder, and I am trying to find the single latest log line with information regarding to version number. In this case, I would hope to select the the second line even though it has a lower version number because it has a more recent time stamp.

Below is my code, I didn't include the code on looping through for folders for the sake of simplicity.

```
            for line in f: #For simplicity sake, I won't include my code above this line because it's just for looping through the folder to find the log lines
            #0strip out \x00 from read content, in case it's encoded differently
            line = line.replace('\x00', '')

            #Regular expressions for finding the log lines in the folder
            RE2 = r"^.+INFO.+Version.+"
            RE3 = r"^.+RC: version"

            previous_version_line = '0'
                version_to_display = '00'
                #Find the general matches, and get the version line with the latest time stamp
                pattern2 = re.compile('('+RE2+'|'+RE3+')', re.IGNORECASE)
                for match2 in pattern2.finditer(line):

                    if parse_version(line) > parse_version(previous_version_line):
                        version_to_display = line
                        previous_version_line = line
                    else:
                        version_to_display = previous_version_line

                    print(version_to_display)
```

Right now the problem seems be with the parse_version comparison, where although the log lines found through the regex should have a higher value than 0, the if statement is always evaluating to false and I am just printing a bunch of 0's.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Find every row with 'version' in them, sort it by time and print latest time along the log message:

```
data = """
2018-05-08T15:47:27.752Z 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 > LVL:2 RC: version: 2.12.1.10452

2018-05-08T21:27:14.2049217Z> <INFO >: Version: 2.10.0.23960

2018-05-08T21:18:53.0428568Z> <INFO >: Version: 2.12.1.26051
"""

import re
from datetime import datetime

data_new = []
for (d, log) in re.findall(r'([\d\-:T\.]+Z)>?\s+(.*)', data):
    if not re.search('version', log, flags=re.I):
        continue
    parts = d.split('.')
    if len(parts[1]) >= 8:
        d = parts[0] + '.' + parts[1][:6] + 'Z'
    data_new.append((datetime.strptime(d, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'), log))

data_new = sorted(data_new, reverse=True)
if data_new:
    t = data_new[0][0].strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
    print(f'Latest version to display:\ntime=[{t}] msg=[{data_new[0][1]}]')
```

Prints:

```
Latest version to display:
time=[2018-05-08T21:27:14.204921Z] msg=[<INFO >: Version: 2.10.0.23960]
```

Caveat:

The Python `datetime` class accepts microseconds only to 6 digits (so this program truncates it).